# My magento 2 is not working after install japanese locale file

Tags: magento2, zend-framework, locale, centos

I have a trouble with my Magento 2 - 500 page error in front and backend.

Error log:

```
2016/05/29 21:28:00 [error] 2681#2681: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/html/var/page_cache" is not writable in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209

Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/var...')
#1 /var/www/html/lib/internal/Cm/Cache/Backend/File.php(82): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/var/www/html/v...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(154): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true)
```

**My Server Centos 7

Nginx 1.10

Php7

Mysql 5.6**

I have already changed 777 `page_cache` directory.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Which is your Magento version? You can read more here: https://github.com/mageinferno/magento2-docker-compose/issues/5

Comment: My magento version is 2.0.7

Answer (score 1):

Try letting the folder have read and write permission (i.e.: changing the permission to 777) to var directory, this worked for me for Magento 2.1.

Ensure you are using recursive option.

```
chmod -Rf 777 <magento install directory>/var/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following command that works for me.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 page_cache
```